# iPhone - Buttons background image

Tags: iphone, button

I've added some buttons to my app with a background image (RESET button below), but the corners are quite as expected. See below:

[image]

The bottom left and right corners of the RESET button seem to be squared. My original image has rounded corners.

Anyone come across this problem before ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing tricky about changing the image for a button(I did it lots of times), as long as you follow a couple of simple steps:

1. your button image must have a transparent background
2. your button must be set as Custom (and NOT Round Rect)
3. your button's background color must have Opacity=0

In order to change the button background color, when you change the color make sure you click on the left side of the color combobox, so that you get presented the color picker. There, you'll have to change the Opacity to 0.

See the image below for a simple demo.
[image]

Good luck with your button

Answer (score 2):

Chek out the the bottom corners of the reset button are rounded and transparent. also set the backcolor of the button as clearcolor. and make the button custom instead of roundedrect.

I suppose the bottom corners of the buton are not transparent so you are facing the problem.

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Suriya, but still have trouble. The botton corners are definitely transparent. I tried flicking between Custom and RoundedRect but still have the same problems. Is it possible to get the 2 tone effect using the button properties instead of the background image ?

Comment: nopes as such theres no such property in button. you can try setting the bgcolor of the button black and also by again removing the wide spaces from the image if there is any. Instead of setting background tru setImage property of button....

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution may be to use something the [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) framework.  It will allow you to create buttons like that (in addition to other styles) without images.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of image do you using for that button, is there alpha channel? Also you could try something like this:

```
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15; // play with this value
yourButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about not setting the background image for the button, but putting a UIImageView with your desired image directly behind the button?

Answer (score 0):

Chek out the the image of the reset button you are using is it in `.png` format and the image back color is clear color. If the problem persists please again make the image you are using there may be some problem with the image you used.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post: http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=232

It has sources for a UIButton+glossy category that allows you to create glossy buttons in apple style. They look pretty much exactly like your buttons. And you wouldn't need to use images at all.